# Angular testing: How to access local variables in a method when testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a method that inside I have a condition that I want to test. Something like:

```
myMethod():void {
  let a:boolean;
  a = this.myService.getValue();

  if (a) { 
    doThis();
  if (!a) { 
    doThat();
```

so in my `it` I did something like:

```
it("Should check if doThis called", () => {
     spyOn(myService, "getValue").andReturn(true);
     component.myMethod();
     expect ...
});
```

But the condition wouldn't work and `a` would never get the "fake" value I mock with the spy

My question is if there's any way I can access / assign value to the local variable of `myMethod()` , `a` , or the only way is to make it global and then I can do in the `it` something like `component.a =`

Thanks.

Comment: Why not pass this.myService.getValue() as a parameter of myMethod?

Comment: Could be an idea, but right now this what the method looks like

Comment: `a` would never get the "fake" value I mock with the spy ?? Why is that ?

Answer (score 2):

```
let a;
spyOn(myService,"getValue").and.callFake(function(data){
      a=data;
      expect(data).not.toBeNull();
component.myMethod();
    })
```

Try this may be help you